# Do invisibility cloaks work underwater?

Tags: harry-potter, invisibility-cloak

As far as I recalled, there isn't even a part that proves these invisibility cloaks work underwater.

I researched my question and tried to browse the sites given to me but the answers aren't there.

It just made me curious these past few days. Harry could have used his invisibility cloak in the Triwizard Tournament (second task). So it makes me wonder... do these cloaks turn invisible underwater?

**NOTE:** Please disregard the reason that ***the cloak will just float.***

Comment: I don't understand the premise of your question. Is there any problem this may solve? How does the answer to this question help you in any way? Have you done any research to finding the answer? Where has your research led you? How did you come up with this question? **OOH nice edit! Just before my comment ;P**

Comment: @Edlothiad thanks for reminding.

Comment: Can I just make a few little comments, can you provide the sites you looked here, might be a good starting point for people researching your answer! Also wouldn't the cloak render Harry's hands and feet useless? How would he swim with the cloak? Would an answer along those lines (discussing how your logic wouldn't exactly work) be acceptable to you?

Comment: Wasn't the main problem surviving underwater?

Comment: Why show a stadium of people, students and professors that you own a invisibility cloak ?

Comment: What makes you think they wouldn't?

Comment: Do you feel that there is something missing from my answer? If not, would you consider accepting it? :)

Answer (score 4):

As there are a few different types of Invisibility cloaks, my answer will be divided into several parts.

### Demiguise cloak

Hair from a [Demiguise](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Demiguise) can be woven together to create an inivisibility cloak. However, the hairs will, over time, became opaque thus making the cloak useless.

The information on Demiguises (or whatever the plural form would be) does not mention any restriction on their invisibility, certainly not that it would not work under water. Since knowing such restrictions would be extremely useful in finding, capturing and caring for the creatures, I find it very likely that our favorite Magizoologist would put in his book (Remember that he put tips on how to evade the law when breeding basilisks in there).

Therefore, my conclusion is that inivisibility cloaks make from Demiguise hair **would work underwater.**

### Disillusionment charm

Another type of Invisibility cloak is the one where a regular cloak is enchanted with a particularly strong disillusionment charm.

The [Disillusionment Charm](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Disillusionment_Charm) is described to make the subject of the spell act like a chameleon, taking on the colour and texture of whatever is behind and around them.

I see no reason why this would not apply underwater as well, and that it simply take on the colour and texture of whatever was around it.

**Yes, this cloak would work under water.**

### The Deathly Hallow cloak

It was created by Death and managed to disguise Ignotus Peverell from Death himself for as long as he wore it. I doubt it would be overcome by something as simple as water.

**Yes, this cloak would work underwater**'

#### Final notes

I am not sure you want the (in my mind) implied question of why Harry didn't use his cloak in the Triwizard Tournament answered, but I'll do so, just in case.

It is implied (by Harry when talking to Moody) that the champions are not allowed any tool other than their wands when completing the tasks (though Harry uses Gillyweed, so I'm not sure about this) and as the Deathly Hallow cloak won't answer to a Summoning charm, he couldn't use Accio to retrieve it.

Also, almost no-one knows that he possesses the cloak, but using it in the TriWiz Tournament would ensure that not only the school, but the entire Magical Britain would know about it.

Comment: Your comment that they are not allowed tools other than their wands is belied by him Accioing his Firebolt for the dragon egg task. I think it's more that they are only allowed to *start* with their wands.

Comment: @JohnP Agreed, which is why I follow-up with the comment that the cloak cannot be Accio'd.

Comment: Did Harry know that the cloak could not be Summoned?  I don't recall that being discussed in GoF (and Rowling *certainly* wouldn't have told us that the cloak was a Hallow at that point in the story).